# Download website from the WayBack Machine

Tags: windows, mirroring, httrack, wayback-machine

I found an excellent website on the WayBack machine which currently doesn't work and the domain is for sale. I wanted to use it offline. I tried using WinHTTrack, but it only saves the homepage, because of the structure of the WayBack Machine.

I am using Windows, and I would appreciate any help with helping me to download it.

Thanks.

Comment: a few more options are described here - https://superuser.com/questions/828907/how-to-download-a-website-from-the-archive-org-wayback-machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just noticed that I have this question from a few years ago still open. While I wasn't able to find a suitable option beyond a generic crawler at the time, multiple options have since popped up on sites like GitHub. While I haven't used any of them personally, I would like to document it here for those still searching for a way to do this.

An example is [hartator/wayback-machine-downloader](https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader), which appears to be platform agnostic (a Ruby .gem). It describes how it works as follows:

> It will download the last version of every file present on Wayback Machine to ./websites/example.com/. It will also re-create a directory structure and auto-create index.html pages to work seamlessly with Apache and Nginx. All files downloaded are the original ones and not Wayback Machine rewritten versions. This way, URLs and links structure are the same as before.

Hope that helps someone who has the same problem I did many years ago. Going to mark as solved with this, unless someone has a better answer.

Comment: That thing really lack a manual on how to serve those files. They are for example all with .php extension and query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Although we generally do not do product recommendations on this site - I would suggest you look into the J-Spider project (http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/).  This product allows the complete downloading of websites as well as doing link tests, site map generation.. all sorts.

Its a pretty useful piece of kit.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openwebspider/ this works for windows (according to its reviews)

Comment: I downloaded it and got the following error. + Reading openwebspider.conf...OK
 - Database1: hosts
 - Server1: localhost
 - Username Database1: user
 - Database2: spiderdb
 - Server2: localhost
 - Username Database2: user
 - Database3: temptables
 - Server3: localhost
 - Username Database3: user
-================-
Failed to connect to database:hosts
Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)