# How to: Download a page from the Wayback Machine over a specified interval

Tags: download, wget, webpage, wayback-machine

What I mean is to download each page available from the Wayback Machine over a specified time period and interval. For example, I want to download each page available from each day from nature.com from January of 2012 to December of 2012. (Not precisely what I want to do, but it's close enough -- and provides a good example.)

wget won't work due to the unique nature of how the Wayback machine works, unfortunately.

Tools like Wayback Machine downloader only download the most recent version of the page, it seems.

Interacting with the IA API seems like a viable route, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Thanks!

Comment: You would definitely need to write a script for this. Maybe cURL?

Comment: I think it'd be possible to write a script and lean on cURL, but I'm unfamiliar with the Memento API that the Internet Archive uses, and  don't' think I've seen it used in this way.

Comment: I need to a) Do multiple sites at once, b) grab a snapshot of each site over a long interval (say, 1998 to 2001), and c) be able to specify how many snapshots I want to take over that interval.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/828907/how-to-download-a-website-from-the-archive-org-wayback-machine

Comment: Same problem. They just want one page, it seems -- the documentation for the WB Machine downloader is vague whether it works over an interval like that, or not.

Comment: Just try it out?

Comment: @duenni Yeah, no, that's not how it's working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way `wayback` URLs are formatted are as follows:

```
http://$BASEURL/$TIMESTAMP/$TARGET
```

Here `BASEURL` is usually `http://web.archive.org/web` (I say usually as I am unsure if it is the only BASEURL)

`TARGET` is self explanatory (in your case `http://nature.com`, or some similar URL)

`TIMESTAMP` is `YYYYmmddHHMMss` when the capture was made (in UTC):

- `YYYY`: Year
- `mm`: Month (2 digit - 01 to 12)
- `dd`: Day of month (2 digit - 01 to 31)
- `HH`: Hour (2 digit - 00 to 23)
- `MM`: Minute (2 digit - 00 to 59)
- `ss`: Second (2 digit - 00 to 59)

In case you request a capture time that doesn't exist, the wayback machine redirects to the closest capture for that URL, whether in the future or the past.

You can use that feature to get each daily URL using `curl -I` (HTTP `HEAD`) to get the set of URLs:

```
BASEURL='http://web.archive.org/web'
TARGET="SET_THIS"
START=1325419200 # Jan 1 2012 12:00:00 UTC (Noon) 
END=1356998400 # Tue Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 2013
if uname -s |grep -q 'Darwin' ; then
    DATECMD="date -u '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -r "
elif uname -s |grep -q 'Linux'; then
    DATECMD="date -u +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d @"
fi


while [[ $START -lt $END ]]; do
    TIMESTAMP=$(${DATECMD}$START)
    REDIRECT="$(curl -sI "$BASEURL/$TIMESTAMP/$TARGET" |awk '/^Location/ {print $2}')"
    if [[ -z "$REDIRECT" ]]; then
        echo "$BASEURL/$TIMESTAMP/$TARGET"
    else
        echo $REDIRECT
    fi
    START=$((START + 86400)) # add 24 hours
done
```

This gets you the URLs that are closest to noon on each day of 2012.
Just remove the duplicates, and, and download the pages.

Note: The Script above can probably be greatly improved to jump forward in case the `REDIRECT` is for a URL more than 1 day in the future, but then it requires deconstructing the returned URL, and adjusting `START` to the correct date value.

Comment: This is great, why? because we have facts and proof of when somebody archived content and web.archive.org has removed archived content in the past.

This script above would save archived content. Awesome.

Comment: It does only download the main file though, and not related js, html, css.

Comment: Actually this script *doesn't download anything*: It just shows the closest URL. You can plug that URL into `wget` or any other `page-getter` with the correct options (notice the `-I` option to `curl`).

Answer (score 4):

There is a ruby gem on Github: https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader

Comment: This is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nice Python package for those more inclined to Python:

https://github.com/jsvine/waybackpack

It's as simple as:

`waybackpack dol.gov -d ~/Downloads/dol-wayback --to-date 1996`