# Trying to Download a flash application to run offline

Tags: download, website, flash, wayback-machine

**Background**

Since, flash support is ending one of my favorite tools to have on hand, www.pixlr.com/editor (Good old flash version), will likely shut down soon.

**Attempted Solutions**

- I have tried to go to the media tab in Mozilla Firefox and download the .swf file, but it will not play in both Firefox (with plugins.http_https_only set to false) and Internet Explorer 11.  I have also tried to render the file with Adobe Flash Projector/Player.  All that renders is a blank screen
- Next, I tried downloading the Wayback machines' copy.  I did this by following the instructions at https://superuser.com/questions/828907/how-to-download-a-website-from-the-archive-org-wayback-machine. I then installed Ruby from https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/, and using the the recommended software from https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader, download the files.  Using both Firefox and Internet Explorer to try to get it to work, and executing index.html, the pages would not load correctly.

File Tree: [image: File Structure of downloaded copy]  Page in IE: [image: What happens when I try to run it in IE, after allowing Active X controls]

**Question:**

How would I go about having an offline copy of this useful tool?  I like to be able to run it without the internet and free of charge.  If I'm going about it correctly, do I need to change a setting, wait longer, or download the page from the Wayback Machine?

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/q/1286248/152004

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found this.
pixlr.findmysoft.com/
Apparently there is an offline version already.

Comment: That look good, but the community at Norton Safe Web seems to think that his is a dangerous website https://safeweb.norton.com/reviews?page=1&url=findmysoft.com.  Just one reason why I thought it would be good to find a way to attempt download pixlr myself.